# Use a string & a variable, concatenated, as a partial arugument in a Bash shell script, avoiding eval if possible

Tags: bash, variable-assignment

I hope to construct a string, expand the value of a variable whose name is equal to the string, and use that value as one of the arguments in a command.  I cannot figure out if it is possible without incorporating the eval command, which most seem to advise against using.

Using a remote system, I wish to iterate through a customer list and collect disk usage statistics for logs.

```
customer0="/volume1/bob"
customer1="/volume1/joe"

num_of_customers=2

for ((i=0;i<$num_of_customers;i++)) 
    do
        ssh username@127.0.0.1 du -sb customer$i
    done
```

The resulting value for customer$i
when i=0
is customer0

The desired outcome is /volume1/bob

Is there a safe way to accomplish this?  I've searched for answers, but I struggle to phrase the question properly.

Comment: BTW, note that ssh basically _does_ do an eval operation; it implicitly starts a remote shell with all the arguments it didn't consume itself concatenated into a single string and passed to that remote shell as code.

Comment: Not that that's relevant here; your real question is about indirect expansion.

Comment: So `customers=( [0]=/volume1/joe [1]=/volume1/bob ); i=0; ssh username@127.0.0.1 "du -sb ${customers[$i]}"` is valid syntax, but it's not proof against `'/volume1/$(rm -rf ~)'` being a value in your array.

Comment: What you end up with if security is a focus is more like `customers=( [0]=/volume1/joe [1]=/volume1/bob ); i=0; printf -v customer_volume_q '%q' "${customers[$i]}"; ssh username@127.0.0.1 "du -sb ${customer_volume_q}"` -- the `%q` escaping is eval-safe (assuming the remote shell is also bash).

Comment: `customer$i` would be the *name* of a variable; nowhere have you tried to expand a variable by that name. `t=customer$i; ssh username@127.0.0.1 "du -sb \"${!t}\""` (Still assuming the value of `${!t}` can't contain double quotes.)

Comment: Or of course, `customer0=/volume/joe; customer1=/volume/bob; i=0; customer_var=customer$i; printf -v customer_volume_q '%q' "${!customer_var}"` if you really do want to stick with the original separate-variable-per-customer world vs an array.

Comment: @chepner, double quotes alone aren't all one's worries when directly substituting values into a string later parsed by a shell; `$(...)` is another.

Comment: Short version: `ssh` is not an implementation of remote procedure calls, so don't expect it to behave like one.

Comment: (also, if you make `customers` an array, you don't need a separate `number_of_customers` variable; you can iterate over `for volume in "${customers[@]}"` to get the volume values directly, or `customer_id in "${!customers[@]}"; do volume=${customers[$volume]}; ...` to get both separately, or use `number_of_customers=${#customers[@]}` to retrieve the length directly).